# Liaison in "tournez à droite/à gauche"

Tags: prononciation, liaisons

I set Waze (the driving directions program) to give me driving instructions in French, just on a whim to hear more French - I'm an advanced beginner level student.

And what I can't help noticing every time is that of the two instructions for turning, the French voice in Waze - I believe there's only one there, called "Morgan" - pronounces "tournez à gauche" without liaison, and "tournez à droite" with [z]. It's very noticeable and unmistakable. And it's also very clear that it's the same person speaking.

Why would they do it this way? It's a trifle I'm sure, but I can't get it out of my mind.

- Maybe the speaker actually consistently pronounces these phrases differently, turning left without liaison and right with? Does that sort of thing happen frequently?
- Perhaps it was just a situational choice when recording the sentences, and to native French speakers the two ways to pronounce sound so similar that they don't even notice there's anything odd?
- Or, on the contrary, maybe they deliberately recorded the two sentences differently, so that when there's background noise in the car, people learn over time to recognize the right direction better?
- Anything else I can't think of?

Comment: Are you really talking of a pattern, all of several occurrences of each of the two sentences being repeated each time with the exact same pronunciation?

Comment: *Morgan* you say ?
Ha!
Yes! After checking, it is indeed a possible choice but I am usually with ***Vanessa***! ;-)
I never noticed that with *"her"* anyway. Which, knowing a little bit about voice synthetizers seems somehow odd because *liaison* is decided at the coding level. Which makes it independent of the rendering. I'll try Morgan tomorrow and come back to this.

Comment: @aCOSwt Driving directions in Waze seem like a small number of set phrases stitched together, so I assumed they were recorded speakers, not voice synthesizers. Not so sure anymore, after your comment; I'll look into finding out.

Comment: @LPH These two sentences are repeated very often while driving, sounding always in the same way, "tournez à droite" with the liaison and "tournez à gauche" without. To contrast, "sortez à droite/à gauche" are both pronounced by the same speaker without the liaison.

Comment: @AnatolyVorobey : You are correct. After careful attention, it does seem that full sentences are recorded. No speach synth. For the record espeak -xq -vfr would render turn'ez2 a (notice the z2) producing the liaison. (In both cases droite et gauche of course). Hence... it is not a bug... Hey... if this is not a bug this is a feature! ;-) In that your third option sounds interesting. But in such a case, *vanessa* would do the same. Anyway... I switch back to "her" ;-)

Answer (score 6):

To answer your bullet points:

- Speakers DO NOT consistently pronounces these phrases differently.
- To native French speakers the two ways to pronounce them DO NOT sound
  similar (the liaison sounds weird).
- If they deliberately recorded the two sentences differently, then it is a mistake. As a native French speaker, I can tell you that no one will use a liaison in this context.

From what I read about the liaison rules (for instance [in wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais)), this case may be considered as an "optional" liaison but in practice, I have never heard anyone pronouncing it.

Comment: Thank you, this was admirably straightforward and helpful.

Comment: Me too! I was trying to imagine a voice using the optional, and it sounded like  someone 74yo addressing the Nation on wireless. Does anyone using other countries' Frenches here have a comment (RE a context where (droite even) might reasonably get liased? I know one Bambara-speaking native French bilingual who does this... and NOTHING else comes to mind after like sersly 5 minutes tryin' to come up with other examples without cheatingPedia recourse.